# Commands out of sync MySql PyQt5 using temporary tables

Tags: mysql, pyqt5

The main program is based on PyQt5 client and stores information on a MySql DB. The issue is that I need to import data from an MS Access DB (done by a QSqlQuery using the QODBC) load in a query (qryImport). I set a temporary table using a  new connection (self.tempDb) to transfer the information to MySQL and I'm running a store procedure on a while loop to insert the data into MySql one record at a time. The problem is that we get the infamous "commands out of sync..."error when running the second while cycle, or in debug mode (PyCharm) as soon as I speed up the process. Could not find an answer to the problem over the net but the "Commands out of sync" form of the MySql Reference Manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html that in my case was not very helpful. 
I also try to close the connection and open the connection and clear the query after executing each cycle which takes care of the out of sync issue, but deletes the temporary tables on the connection in both cases besides not being very efficient.
Most of the information I found about it is referring either to PHP or python's MSQLDB, so I was not able to implement the manual´s recommendation of using msql_free_result() or msql_store_result() since I couldn't  figure out how to do it.
I would appreciate any advise addressing this issue.
In the mean time I will try to use a permanent table as a workaround - that I don't like - or to export the query from MS Access to MySql eventually.

````
# ............................................
qryImport.seek(-1)
qry = QSqlQuery(self.tempDb)
qry.prepare("CALL importhorses_loaddata(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
while qryImport.next():
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(0)))  # accessid
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(1))) # name
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(2))) #rp
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(3).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))) #BirthDate
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(4))) #sexid
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(5))) #coatid
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(6))) #isbreakable
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(7))) #isBroke
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(8))) #isPlayer
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(9))) #Father
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(10))) #Mother
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(qryImport.value(11))) #UbicacionID
    qry.addBindValue(QVariant(self.importDate.date().toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))) #ImportDate
    qry.exec()
    if qry.lastError().type() != 0:
        raise DataError("importHorses", qry.lastError().text())
    if qry.first():
        print(qry.value(0))
# .....................................```
````

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE importhorses_loaddate(IN p_accessid INT,........., IN p_inputdate DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE code CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE msg TEXT;
DECLARE _horsebaseid INT;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
    code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SELECT code, msg;
    ROLLBACK;
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT horsebaseid FROM horses WHERE horsebaseid = p:accessid INTO _horsebaseid;
    IF _horsebaseid != p_accessid THEN
        INSERT INTO importedhorses(horsebaseid, ..........., inputdate)
        VALUES(p_accessid, ......................, p_inputdate);
    END IF;
    COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by placing the query definition inside the while block and clearing the query at the end of the block (qry.clear() one I change the table from temporary to permanent (temporary tables get deleted).

Comment: I have a similar problem with another stored procedure just retrieving a Select query from temporary tables. I couldn't make it run until I changed the using of bound parameters in the query calling procedure for a format string. It's my guess that this behavior may be a bug in the QMYSQL3 PyQt5 driver..